# Calling a ActiveRecord class method for ActiveRecord_Relation as a receiver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activerecord-relation

I want to create a `class method` for a class inherits `ActiveRecord:Base`.
What the method need to do is add where clauses based on the options and it works well.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.list_by_params(params={})
    articles = self
    articles = articles.where(author_id: params[:author_id]) unless params[:author_id].blank?
    articles = articles.where(category_id: params[:category_id]) unless params[:category_id].blank?
    articles = articles.where("created_at > ?", params[:created_at].to_date) unless params[:created_at].blank?
    articles
  end

end
```

This code works fine in case of the call such as:

```
articles = Article.list_by_params({author_id: 700})
#=> Works fine as I expected.

articles = Article.joins(:authors).list_by_params({author_id: 700})
#=> Works fine as I expected.
```

However, the problem is that, if I want to call the `list_by_params` without filtering params, then **it lose its former relations**. For example:

```
articles = Article.joins(:authors).list_by_params({})
#=> articles is just a `Article` (not an ActiveRecord_Relation) class itself without joining :authors.
```

Is there any chance that I made a mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you define instance method (not a class one) `list_by_params` and I don't see any reason why this `Article.list_by_params` is NOT throwing a NoMethod error.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If my answer did not work. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope).

I would do something like this

```
scope :for_author,  lambda { |author| where(author_id: author) unless author.blank? }
scope :in_category, lambda { |category| where(category_id: category) unless category.blank? }
scope :created_after,  lambda { |date| where('created_at > ?', date.to_date) unless date.blank? }

scope :list_by_params, lambda do |params|
  for_author(params[:author_id])
  .in_category(params[:category_id])
  .created_after(params[:created_at])
end
```

Now you can reuse the components of your query. Everything has a names and it gets easier to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

For the self explanation, I've solved the problems by using `where(nil)`.

Actually, `Model.scoped` returned anonymous scope but the method has been deprecated since Rails version 4. **Now, `where(nil)` can replace the functionality.**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.list_by_params(params={})
    articles = where(nil)  # <-- HERE IS THE PART THAT I CHANGED.
    articles = articles.where(author_id: params[:author_id]) unless params[:author_id].blank?
    articles = articles.where(category_id: params[:category_id]) unless params[:category_id].blank?
    articles = articles.where("created_at > ?", params[:created_at].to_date) unless params[:created_at].blank?
    articles
  end

end
```